# Unexpected behaviour in vim solarized with urxvt

Tags: ubuntu, vim, urxvt

I get the following garbage characters as `@k` displayed in vim when using solarized in urxvt. However when i resize the window the issue disappears. note that I am using i3wm as my window manager.

My [.vimrc](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8776395/) and my [.Xdefaults](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8776361/)

[image: Vim screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arose due to a misconfiguration in the vim-airline plugin.
solution was to remove the plugin ans reinstall it :)